# Как собрать P7 Logger?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, сборка

Помогите разобраться как собрать P7 Logger. Скачал исходники с [оффициального сайта](http://baical.net/downloads.html). В документации написано: [image: из документации]

У меня установлены `Win10 x64, VS Community 2019, Qt5.15, CMake 3.15`. Так же установил компонент(может быть не тот, в инсталере их там несколько было) `Spectre` [image: компонент Spectre]

После перехода в папку `_build_`, Пробовал по разному:

```
> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ".."
```

Вывод:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine версии 16.7.0+b89cb5fde для .NET Framework
    (C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

    Сборка начата 14.08.2020 12:15:16.
    Проект "D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" в узле 1 (целевые объекты по умолчанию).
    PrepareForBuild:
      Создание каталога "x64\Debug\".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(458,5): error MSB8040: для этого проекта требуются библиотеки с устранением рисков Spectre. Установите их с помощью установщика Visual Studio (вкладка "Отдельные компоненты") для всех используемых архитектур и наборов инструментов. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c [D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Сборка проекта "D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" завершена (целевые объекты по умолчанию) с ошибкой.

    Ошибка сборки.

    "D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (1) ->
    (Целевой объект PrepareForBuild) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(458,5): error MSB8040: для этого проекта требуются библиотеки с устранением рисков Spectre. Установите их с помощью установщика Visual Studio (вкладка "Отдельные компоненты") для всех используемых архитектур и наборов инструментов. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj
```

И так:

```
> cmake ..
```

Вывод:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine версии 16.7.0+b89cb5fde для .NET Framework
    (C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

    Сборка начата 14.08.2020 13:27:36.
    Проект "D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" в узле 1 (целевые объекты по умолчанию).
    PrepareForBuild:
      Создание каталога "x64\Debug\".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(458,5): error MSB8040: для этого проекта требуются библиотеки с устранением рисков Spectre. Установите их с помощью установщика Visual Studio (вкладка "Отдельные компоненты") для всех используемых архитектур и наборов инструментов. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c [D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Сборка проекта "D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" завершена (целевые объекты по умолчанию) с ошибкой.

    Ошибка сборки.

    "D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (1) ->
    (Целевой объект PrepareForBuild) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(458,5): error MSB8040: для этого проекта требуются библиотеки с устранением рисков Spectre. Установите их с помощью установщика Visual Studio (вкладка "Отдельные компоненты") для всех используемых архитектур и наборов инструментов. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c [D:\UserFiles\Documents\QtProjects\testCPP\libP7Client_v5.5\_bild_\CMakeFiles\3.15.0-rc2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

        Предупреждений: 0
        Ошибок: 1

    Прошло времени 00:00:00.18


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/UserFiles/Documents/QtProjects/testCPP/libP7Client_v5.5/_bild_/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

---

**udp:** Подскажите который нужно установить?
[image: vs2019 specture x64]
[image: vs2019 specture x64 2]

Comment: там там в тексте ошибки прям все пишет, что нужно сделать. "error MSB8040: для этого проекта требуются библиотеки с устранением рисков Spectre. "

Comment: @KoVadim который?

Comment: проверил у себя. проект собрался и никаких проблем не было. Правда у меня не установлено ничего с поддержкой spectre

Comment: а версия Visual Studio какая у вас?

Comment: точно такая же.

Comment: Может нужен /QSpectre https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2019